# HTML list element shifts other elements right there after

Tags: html

When I save as .html file I get this an alignment problem. After first ul or ol, the proceeding element will be approx two tabs misaligned for heading, one tab misaligned for the list itself. Again the next element is further shifted. I've tried style to align or float it left, including within div. Is this some sort of rule that occurs I'm unaware of specific to lists.

```html
<h3>another title</h3>
<ul>
  <li>this</li>
  <li>is</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>list</li>
  <li>that</li>
  <li>of</li>
  <li>sets</li>
  <li>next</li>
  <li>list</li>
<ul>

<h3>another other title</h3>
<ol>
  <li>this</li>
  <li>list</li>
  <li>causes</li>
  <li>the </li>
  <li>next</li>
  <li>list</li>
  <li>to</li>
  <li>shift</li>
  <li>right</li>
  <li>as</li>
  <li>well</li>
<ol>

<h3>oh no!</h3>
<i>Please contact <b>help</b></i>
```

Comment: make a fiddle so we can see your DOM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing closing brackets: replace the closing `<ul>` and `<ol>` with `</ul>` and `</ol>`. Btw the reason why this is happening is because the second list is the first one's bullet point, and so on

Answer (score 1):

You should notice the difference between the start-tags (like `<ul>` and `<ol>`) and their close tags (like `</ul>` and `</ol>`). You just need to change the start tag at the end of each list to an end-tag, and the everything will work:

```html
<h3>another title</h3>
<ul>
  <li>this</li>
  <li>is</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>list</li>
  <li>that</li>
  <li>of</li>
  <li>sets</li>
  <li>next</li>
  <li>list</li>
</ul> <!-- before on your code: <ul> -->

<h3>another other title</h3>
<ol>
  <li>this</li>
  <li>list</li>
  <li>causes</li>
  <li>the </li>
  <li>next</li>
  <li>list</li>
  <li>to</li>
  <li>shift</li>
  <li>right</li>
  <li>as</li>
  <li>well</li>
</ol> <!-- before on your code: <ol> -->

<h3>oh no!</h3>
<i>Please contact <b>help</b></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing closing brackets

```
</ul> 


</ol>
```